# How to check if TTTAttributedLabel is currently truncated

Tags: ios, tttattributedlabel

I need a way to check whether a `TTTAttributedLabel` (https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) is truncated or not and perform custom logic depending on that.

I am looking for some hypothetical property like `BOOL isTruncated`. How do I do it?

Comment: what is `TTTAttributedLabel` ? is it any library ? If yes then include it's link in question!

Comment: why don't just calculate width of the screen and check if it fits in bounds?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the below method to get what you want:
```

`

```
func isTruncated(label:UILabel) -> Bool{
       let text: String = label.text
       if text.isEmpty()
        {
          return false
        }
         let boundingBox = text.boundingRect(with: label.frame.size.width,   options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: label.font!], context: nil)
            return label.frame.size.height >= boundingBox.height 
        }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you have single line label then you can do something like,

```
CGSize size = [yourLabel.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : yourLabel.font}];
if (size.width > yourLabel.bounds.size.width) {

    NSLog(@"your font is truncated!");
}
```

you can create one method which return `bool`(truncated or not) and accepts label as a parameter!

Comment: I've thought about it but I'm not sure if it would calculate everything correctly as it also accounts for links (with different font weights) and truncation token.